# How can I change the color of text with a CSS transition?

Tags: html, css, animation, css-transitions

I have some text:

```
<span class='my-class'>Some text</span>
```

I want the text to start out green then (in 10 seconds), turn to blue. I don't want it to trigger on a hover or anything, but rather as soon as the element with the class exists.

Comment: You are looking for css animation, just give time to 10s and done. Very simple. Transition s don't change color. Only solution is css animation or Javascript.

Comment: why do you want to use it? just for hovering or you want a text with a fix color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can see how color change with adding `transition duration` or `transition delay`. it works with even 3 colors. if you want to change to 2 color you can easly delete `50% {color:blue;}`.

using `duration and delay` is another way that I mention it before but using  @-webkit-keyframes and % is more flexible.

HTML codes

```
<span class='my-class'>Some text</span>
```

css code:

```
.my-class {
    -webkit-animation:name 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes name {
    0% {color:magenta;}
    50% {color:blue;}
    100%{color:green}
}
```

and this is the jsfiddle link
[sample](https://jsfiddle.net/ock0vgLy/)

Comment: How do I specify the 2 colors?

Comment: do you want to use it as an hover or just two color?

Comment: No hover - just start at color1 and then transition to color2

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this by using [animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) and using `animation-delay: 10s;` and also `keyframes` to change colors - NO hovers

It will start from green and after 10 seconds it will turn blue as you wanted.

Run snippet below.

```css
.my-class {
  animation-name: blue;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 10s;
  font-size: 4em;
  color: green;
}

@keyframes blue {
    to { color: blue; }
}
```

```html
<span class='my-class'>Some text </span> 
<small>I will turn blue in 10 seconds </small>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, it takes 10s to go from green to blue.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<span class='my-class'>Some text</span>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.my-class{
animation-delay:8s;
  animation-name: color;
  animation-duration: 2s;
color:green;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;  

}
@keyframes color {
  from {color: green;}
  to {color: blue;}
}
```

#Demo
https://jsbin.com/zusihologo/edit?css